# CRUD OOPHP + Postgres error in my function list

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm developing a CRUD Application with PHP OO and I have a problem with this listing function in postgres, is showing an error in my php page HTML:

> ( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\CRUD-Postgres\pessoa.php on line 47

Function:

```
function busca() {
    require_once ('db_conecta.php');       
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM pessoas ");
    $stmt = pg_query($con, $query);
    $resultados = pg_fetch_array($stmt);
    $pessoas = array();
    foreach ($resultados as $item) {
        $pessoa = new Pessoa();
        $pessoa -> setId($item['id']);
        $pessoa -> setNome($item['nome']);
        $pessoa -> setFone($item['fone']);
        $pessoa -> setEmail($item['email']);
        array_push($pessoas, $pessoa);
    }
    return $pessoas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pg_fetch_Array` will return `false` if there are no rows to retrieve, try outputting the value before the `foreach`.

It also only returns a single row.  Perhaps you intended to use `pg_fetch_all`.